# ui:insert not working

Tags: jsf, facelets

I saw many threads here but none of them couldn't help.

**This is my index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="templates/template.xhtml">
</ui:composition>
```

**And this is my template.xhml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <f:view contentType="text/html" locale="en">
        <h:head>
            <title><ui:insert name="title">Master Data</ui:insert></title>
            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="layout.css"/>
            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jsfcrud.css"/>
            <h:outputScript library="js" name="jsfcrud.js"/>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="chaptersMenuColumn,chaptersContentColumn">
                <h:form id="form1">
                    <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu label="Master Data Sections">
                            <p:menuitem value="KPI" actionListener="#{kpiBean.setPage('create')}" update=":form2:secondPart"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Queues" actionListener="#{kpiBean.setPage('view')}" update=":form2:secondPart"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="States"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Causes"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="SubCauses"/>
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:menu> 
                </h:form>
                <h:form id="form2">
                    <h:panelGroup id="secondPart" layout="block">
                        <h2>Hi</h2>
                        <!-- <ui:include src = "/views/#{kpiBean.page}.xhtml"/>  -->
                        <ui:insert name="emptyPage"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

**And this my empty.xhtml:**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:define name="emptyPage">
        <h3>This is an empty page</h3>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I don't understand why can't I see the content of empty.xhtml in the index page?

Comment: why not working with an includ ?!?

Comment: `ui-insert` != PrimeFaces but plain jsf. And it is PrimeFace**s** ;-)

Comment: @YagamiLight yeah it is driving me crazy with both 2 methods not working

Comment: read this post [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Comment: @YagamiLight thanks I read it many times but what I need is the dynamic update of *secondPart*